# How to minimize the loss?

Tags: tensorflow, regression, conv-neural-network

This should be a regression problem.

I would like the Neural Network to be able to estimate the length of a line, in pixel, from an image, like this 3 images, each image is 200 x 200 pcs:

a)[image: Train_1]b)[image: Train_2]c)[image: Train_3]

Training image of 6000 pcs, and validation image of 1000 pcs.

The labels are the distance in pixel:

a) 1.205404496424333018e+02

b) 1.188780888137086436e+02

c) 1.110180165558725918e+02

Here is my training code:

```
img_size = 200

def preprocess_image(image):
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
  image = tf.image.resize(image, [img_size, img_size])
  image /= 255.0  # normalize to [0,1] range

  return image

def load_and_preprocess_image(path):
  image = tf.read_file(path)
  return preprocess_image(image)

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
BATCH_SIZE = 16

train_labels = np.loadtxt("train_labels.txt")
val_labels = np.loadtxt("test_labels.txt")

train_images = sorted(glob.glob("train_img/img_*.jpg"))
val_images = sorted(glob.glob("test_img/img_*.jpg"))

steps_per_epoch_count=tf.ceil(len(train_images)/BATCH_SIZE)

train_path_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_images)
val_path_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(val_images)

train_image_ds = train_path_ds.map(load_and_preprocess_image, 
num_parallel_calls = AUTOTUNE)
train_label_ds = 
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.cast(train_labels, tf.float32))
train_image_label_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_image_ds, 
train_label_ds))

val_image_ds = val_path_ds.map(load_and_preprocess_image, 
num_parallel_calls = AUTOTUNE)
val_label_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.cast(val_labels, tf.float32))
val_image_label_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((val_image_ds, val_label_ds))


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(16,3,3, input_shape=(img_size, 
img_size, 3), activation = 'relu'),

tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(32,3,3, activation = 'relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
# tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(64,3,3, activation = 'relu'),
# tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.05),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.01),
    loss = "mean_squared_error",
    metrics = ["mean_absolute_error", "mean_squared_error"]
    )

train_ds = train_image_label_ds.apply(tf.data.experimental.shuffle_and_repeat(buffer_size=len(train_images)))
train_ds = train_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)


val_ds = val_image_label_ds.apply(
  tf.data.experimental.shuffle_and_repeat(buffer_size=len(val_images)))
val_ds = val_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
val_ds = val_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

history = model.fit(
    train_ds, 
    epochs = 80, 
    validation_data = val_ds,
    steps_per_epoch = 374,
    validation_steps = 62
    )
```

However, this is the train vs eval mean_squared_error plot:
[image: Plot]

Question:

1. Why is the validation loss not stable?
2. The average Mean Squared Error is about 400 in training, which seems too high. What modification I can do to improve the estimation?

EDIT:

This is my latest model:

Learning rate = 0.01

Batch size = 16

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(16,3,3, input_shape=(img_size, img_size, 3), activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(32,3,3, activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.relu), #, kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.relu), #, kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.relu), #, kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")
])
```

The output looks like this:
[image: Very closed train and validation loss]

As you can see, the train and validation loss is almost identical. The mse loss are both stabilized around 2393, which square root to 48.91 pixel error, quite high.

What advice to lower it further? Is it normal?

Comment: 1) Because it is not the training data. It seems your model may be overfitting, so you may consider using dropout and/or regularization (weight decay) to improve that 2) Considering that is MSE, you could take the square root of the loss to get an idea of the scale, which would be 20. That is not great but not so terrible either. The only path to improving your results is experimenting with the network architecture (layers, sizes, activation functions, ...).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Tried several hyperparameters, the training and validation loss are more stable, but still quite high, around 600, with 500 epochs. Could it because my problem is about measuring line, but maxpooling is reducing the image?

Comment: Since I executed Maxpooling twice in my network, I tried to reduce the labels value by 4 times, and retrain. But the result is the same loss value.